# Inserting multiple rows into a table based on another

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am looking at creating a lookup table to join with one of our existing tables. The strucuture of the existing table is as follows:

```
Version| CompanyNumber|EffDate   |ExpDate   |Indicator
------------------------------------------------------
 1     |     2        |xx/xx/xxxx|xx/xx/xxxx| 0
 2     |     2        |xx/xx/xxxx|xx/xx/xxxx| 1
```

The new table has the structure of this and should be populated like so:

```
ID | Version | Form
---------------------
1  |   1     |  1
2  |   1     |  2
3  |   1     |  3
4  |   2     |  3
```

What I am struggling with is populating the new table with the data in the example above. If the indicator is 0 I will always populate the form with 1, 2 and 3 for the version.

So if the indicator is 0 I want to add form 1, 2, and 3 for each version and if the indicator is 1 I only want to add form 3.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Judging by your data ... if you just join by version, you'll get what you want, but will you always have form 1,2,3 in new table if Indicator is 0?

Comment: The issue is I need to populate the second table with data that looks like that.

Comment: ohhhhh ... I get it now ... well just select Version and Indicator one by one, and go with IF statement. You'll get that insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a query like this to perform `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO Table2(Version, Form)
SELECT Version, x.v
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN (VALUES (1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1)) AS x(i, v)
ON IIF(Table1.Indicator = 0, 3, Table1.Indicator) >= x.i
```

If `Indicator` is equal to `0`, then 3 rows are being inserted, otherwise only 1 row is inserted.

**Note:** I assume that field `ID` of `Table2` is an `IDENTITY` field.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes it will work. There was a bug in the query. Fixed it.

Comment: IIF is only a SQL Server 2012 function would you have the equivilant in 2008?

Comment: @JamieBabineau You can use a `CASE` expression: `CASE WHEN Table1.Indicator = 0 THEN 3 ELSE Table1.Indicator END`